# Stored Procedure dynamic / generic where

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, where-clause

I know there a several Answers to this question but it i thing non of them fit my needs so here comes my question

based on this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b187/25) i will explain you what i'm trying to achieve.

How you can see it's just a simple table of persons so now i want to get a person by his id so i have to write a simple query `SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE  PersonID =@PersonID;` to get him i can do this now for any possible combination and i will get tons of stored procedures just for this Table

So here is my question how do i create a stored procedure that combines all this functionality in one. So that i will be able to just give here the LastName 'Schmidt' and get all Schmidt's. than ask her for all Paul's in NewYork

to make it easyer:

- it's enough if this Stored Procedure is only able to handle "AND"
- also it's enough if it select all columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
WHERE PersonID  = ifnull(@PersonID,personID)
  AND LastName  = ifnull(@LastName,LastName)
  AND FirstName = ifnull(@FirstName, FirstName)
  AND Address   = ifnull(@Address,Address)
  AND City      = ifnull(@City,City)
```

and see it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b187/42).

Comment: could you please take a look at [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19007151/1993545) it is related to your answer, thanks in advance