# Generic select doesn't work with bit type

Tags: sql, sql-server, generics, select, stored-procedures

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18469483/1993545)

i tryed to create a Select for on of my table

```
ALTER PROCEDURE _Einrichtung_Select

    -- Parameters with default values
        @EinrichtungId      AS int          = NULL,
        @EinrichtungName    AS nvarchar(50) = NULL,
        @IsKueche           AS bit          = NULL,
        @RefEinrichtungId   AS int          = NULL,
        @RefSpeiseplantypId AS int          = NULL

AS

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- generic SELECT query
        SELECT  *
        FROM    Einrichtung
        WHERE   EinrichtungId       = ISNULL(@EinrichtungId,        EinrichtungId)
        AND     EinrichtungName     = ISNULL(@EinrichtungName,      EinrichtungName)
        AND     IsKueche            = ISNULL(@IsKueche,             IsKueche)
        AND     RefEinrichtungId    = ISNULL(@RefEinrichtungId,     RefEinrichtungId)
        AND     RefSpeiseplantypId  = ISNULL(@RefSpeiseplantypId,   RefSpeiseplantypId)

        ORDER BY EinrichtungName

    RETURN
```

but i  got a problem with the bit type [example sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cedb/22) like you can see it should return 4 rows but it only returns 3 so what do i miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you can have `null` as values of your columns. And SQL have [three-value logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29), so checking `null = null` will return `UNKNOWN` instead of `TRUE` (as you may expect).
I think this query will help you:

```
select *
from myTable
where
    (@EinrichtungId is null or EinrichtungId = @EinrichtungId) and
    (@EinrichtungName is null or EinrichtungName = @EinrichtungName) and
    (@IsKueche is null or IsKueche = @IsKueche) and
    (@RefEinrichtungId is null or RefEinrichtungId = @RefEinrichtungId) and
    (@RefSpeiseplantypId is null or RefSpeiseplantypId = @RefSpeiseplantypId)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cedb/25)</kbd>**

Comment: ah you are right i thought (null == null) => true, now it works like i expected :) thanks